# LibGDX: How to use AssetManager with Texture Atlases?

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, assets, asset-management

A similar question was asked before, but I never saw an answer.

How does one load individual texture regions that derive from a texture atlas using assetManager? I know that assetManager relies on a file name. (the file name could be the .pack file, for instance).

How would this work for individual texture regions? What would go in the file handle?

How would I do this:

manager.load("sprite_sheet.txt", TextureAtlas.class);

but with a textureRegion from that atlas?

Answer (score 1):

You don't, the asset is the `TextureAtlas`, not the individual `TextureRegions`.

This means that you let the `AssetManager` load the `TextureAtlas` and you manage getting the regions out of it yourself.

One way of doing this is the way Andreas Ohelke does it in Learning libGDX Development where a `Assets` class load the `TextureAtlas` and then simple wrapper classes are responsible for getting the regions in an easy to access format:

```
public class Assets {
    private static final AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> SPRITE_ATLAS = new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("graphics/sprites.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);


    public SpriteAssets sprites;

    public void init(AssetManager assetManager) {
        TextureAtlas spriteAtlas = assetManager.load(SPRITE_ATLAS, TextureAtlas.class);

        assetManager.finishLoading();


        sprites = new SpriteAssets(assetManager.get(SPRITE_ATLAS));

    }

    public class SpriteAssets {

        public final TextureRegion ship;
        public final TextureRegion player;
        public final TextureRegion enemy;

        public SpriteAssets(TextureAtlas atlas) {
            ship = atlas.findRegion("ship");
            player = atlas.findRegion("player");
            enemy = atlas.findRegion("enemy");
        }
    }
}
```

([full example](https://github.com/wlk/canyon-bunny/blob/master/core/src/com/packtpub/libgdx/canyonbunny/game/Assets.java))